# dart SDK version doesn't seem to change

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code

I had `Dart` SDK with version 2.16 installed and worked fine on my machine.

I tried to install the Dart with version 3 which is currently in development (3.0.0-0.0.dev), so in order to try it, I replaced the path of the Dart sdk in the environment variables with the path of the new dart with version 3, Then I created a new project on VScode, and this showed up:

[image]

Here I am writing code with the `Records` feature ( Which exists only in that Dart 3 dev version), and this error shows up:

```
This requires the 'records' language feature to be enabled.
Try updating your pubspec.yaml to set the minimum SDK constraint to 3.0.0 or higher, and running 'pub get'.
```

But on my `pubspec.yaml`:

```
  environment:
  sdk: '>=3.0.0-0.0.dev <3.0.0'
```

but that error is thrown, and I have no idea what cause it and how I can fix it and run the code successfully.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure pubspec considers a version with a [prerelease suffix](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec#version) to be less than the version without the suffix. So in that sense you haven't met the minimum constraint.

Comment: If you want to explicitly enable experimental features, see https://dart.dev/tools/experiment-flags

Comment: @mmcdon20 I didn't set manually the version, it's set automatically when I created it

Comment: @jamesdlin Thank you so much, this was the piece of information I missed, it's running now fine, thank you again.

Comment: @jamesdlin, is there any flag or way to allow all experimental without needing to add their flag in the launch.json ?

Comment: @Gwhyyy mmcdon's point is that 3.0.0-0.0.dev < 3.0.0, so if a feature requires 3.0.0, it's impossible to satisfy that constraint with 3.0.0-0.0.dev.